# Maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let  $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$
Is it true that:

1. $dim_{\mathbb{C}}R =3$
2. $(x) $ is maximal ideal of $R$

I am not familiar with the dimension in ring theory, is it really meaning vectorspace dimension? How to clarify this?

How $(x)$ is treated as a subset of $R$ here, to ask if it is maximal? 
I didn't got a clarity on these.

Comment: Yes for a $k$-algebra it is natural to ask its $k$-vector space dimension. What elements does $(x)$ contain ?

Comment: $(x)$ in polynomial ring $R[x]$ means all polynomials without constant term and is ideal in $R[x]$. But here

Comment: What is the dimension and basis of $R$ ?

Comment: Since $x^2+1$ is reducible, how we can talk about $R$ explicitely

Comment: $I=  (x^2+1) \Bbb{C}[x]$, $R =\Bbb{C}[x]/I= \{ f+I, f \in \Bbb{C}[x]\}$ (its elements are subsets of $\Bbb{C}[x]$) with addition and multiplication $(f+I)+(g+I) =(f+g)+I, (f+I)(g+I)=fg+I$

Comment: Still i didin't got the answer

Comment: If you don't make any effort nobody can help you. You are supposed to clarify since the beginning what you don't understand, not copy an exercice which you don't understand any single word, this holds for the comments too.

Comment: Can I tell like this, Since $x^2+1$ is reducible R is not a field, but Since degree of $x^2+1$ is 2, this ring will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$  Hence dimension is 2.

Comment: What is the isomorphism. $\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{C\times C}$. That the dimension is $2$ is trivial : any polynomial is of the form $a+bx+g(x)(x^2+1)$ for some $g(x)\in \Bbb{C}[x]$. Once we know the basis $1,x$ then $(x) = x(\Bbb{C}+x\Bbb{C})=x\Bbb{C}+x^2\Bbb{C}=...$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the ring $R={\Bbb C}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ has the monomial standard basis $\{\bar 1, \bar x\}$, since $\bar x^2+\bar 1=\overline{x^2+1}=\bar 0$ in $R$, where $\bar a = a +\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is the residue class modulo the ideal.

By the isomorphism theorems for rings, the ideals in ${\Bbb C}[x]$ containing $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ correspond one-to-one with the ideals of $R$.

The maximal ideals of ${\Bbb C}[x]$ are of the form $\langle x-a\rangle$ with $a\in{\Bbb C}$. From here you get the 2nd answer.

Comment: But by a theorem Ideals of quotient ring , say $R/I$ have a one to one correspondence with the ideals of $R$  which containing $I$., In our case there are only two prime ideals of $C[x]$ which containing ideal $(x^2+1)$ are $(x+i)$ and $( x-i)$. Hence, there is only two maximal ideals for our ring $R$, whether $(x)$ is one of them.  (Am I correct with above arguments, then how (x) is maximal) is (x) is an ideal here?